"No Google.com accounts exist in the Auth Emulator." Firebase emulator-created accounts also not appearing
First time working with firebase auth. I have a minimal example set up (shown below) and the auth emulator up and running.
When I call signInWithRedirect with the Google Auth Provider, I get the message:
"No Google.com accounts exist in the Auth Emulator" and the option to create a new account with dummy data. Regardless of what I put in that form, whether the dummy account has an @gmail.com address or not, no sign-in seems to occur, and the account doesn't appear in the auth emulator UI.
Furthermore, accounts I put in the auth emulator UI (which require me to add a password or phone number, which makes me think they're not going to work with the Google Auth Provider anyway) don't appear as options in my app.
I've confirmed that:

my firebase config is correct
the emulator is running on port 9099
no errors are logged during this flow

I suspect I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the auth/emulator/provider is meant to work, but where do I go from here?
Code:
//firebase.js
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); //config not shown, it's correct

export const auth = getAuth();
export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://127.0.0.1:9099");
}
export default app;

//app.js

import app, { auth, provider } from "./firebase";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


  const handleSignIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        setUser(result.user);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };

 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      getRedirectResult(getAuth()) //tried this with just auth as well, was not 100% sure if the object needed to be refreshed here)
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {user ? (
        <div>Hello {user.name}</div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          Please log in:{" "}
          <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In With Google</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

